# how to surround a word using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

Tags: regex, string, quotes, match, surround

I've seen this topic:
[How to surround text with brackets using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654723/how-to-surround-text-with-brackets-using-regex)
but that's on ruby and I don't know the analog for C#
I tried

```
text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, ' '  + SpecialWord + ' ', " \"\0\" ", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but that didn't insert my matched word. So how do I surround my matched word with quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `\b` to match the word boundary, rather than a space.

You need to use `$0` instead of `\0` too.

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b" + SpecialWord + @"\b", @" ""$0"" ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$` instead of `\` for the backreference. Also, put your special word in parenthesis and reference that sub group, otherwise, you will get the complete matched string:

```
text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
                         text, "\\b("  + SpecialWord + ")\\b", " \"$1\" ", 
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Explanation:

- `\b` is a word boundary, i.e. a space, the end of the string, a full stop etc.
- `$0` will match the whole match, i.e. including the word boundary, whereas `$1` matches the first sub group, i.e. the part in the parenthesis.

Comment: I don't think parentheses are necessary if you use `\b` as it's zero-width, so in this case `$0` and `$1` are identical.