# What is the purpose of .*\\?

Tags: regex, r

I have been playing around with `list.files()` and I wanted to only list `001.csv` through `010.csv` and I came up with this command:

```
list_files <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".*\\000|010", full.names = TRUE)
```

This code gives me what I want, but I do not fully understand what is happening with the pattern argument. How does `pattern =  .*\\\000` work?

Comment: How did you come up with that command? I'm shocked it worked. I would think something like `"00\\d\\.csv|010\\.csv"`, depending on how specific you need to be.

Comment: I didn't think `"\\0"` was a valid regex escapement anyway, unless it's being treated as just `"0"`

Comment: Gregor, I started with variations of 00*, 0*0, *00, then read about .*\\ somewhere. I messed around with .*\\ without knowing what it really does.  This just ended up working for me.

Comment: Related (re: `\\0`), but I'm still confused: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4654723/903061

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\\0` is a backreference that inserts the whole regex match to that point. Compare the following to see what that can mean:

```
sub("he", "", "hehello")
## [1] "hello"
sub("he\\0", "", "hehello")
## [1] "llo"
```

With strings like `"001.csv"` or `"009.csv"`,  what happens is that the `.*` matches zero characters, the `\\0` repeats those zero characters one time, and the `00` matches the first two zeros in the string. Success!

This pattern **won't** match `"100.csv"` or `"010.csv"` because it can't find anything to match that is doubled and then immediately followed by two `0`s. It **will**, though, match `"1100.csv"`, because it matches `1`, then doubles it, and then finds two `0`s.

So, to recap, `".*\\000"` matches any string beginning with `xx00` where `x` stands for any substring of zero or more characters. That is, it matches anything repeated twice and then folllowed by two zeros.

Comment: A file named `100.c` is matched by `".*00"` but is not matched by `".*\\000"`. So `\\0` has some effect.

Comment: I've been playing with this test string: `c("001.csv", "008.csv", "007.csv", "009.csv", "010.csv", "011.csv", 
"101.csv", "110.csv", "100.csv")`

Comment: @unutbu -- OK, with that helpful pointer, I think I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this explains all the cases I've looked at.

Comment: Same here, including `"xyz123xyz12300abc.csv"` ;)

Comment: Hey that's cool - I never knew this one! So it's like the opposite to `\\K` which I use [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23964843/1478381)?